# Display request path in Chrome DevTools network panel

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome-devtools

I make the following call using `jQuery`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://domain/..etc../calendars/",
// ...
});
```

which returns the results I need.

The issue I have is this call is represented like this in the developer tools:

[image]

The call is simply displayed as:

```
?_=1443327272355
```

This makes the call difficult to find in amongst all of the other calls without filtering and searching.

Is there a way I can display the call as at least:

```
/calendars/?_=1443327272355
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your best option is to use ***large request rows***. In order to see large request rows, click the "Network Settings" on the right of the Network panel, and select *"Use large request rows"*.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

JQuery appends timestamp with every request for browser to prevent caching. 
You could do something like this to prevent it from happening

$.ajaxSetup({'cache':true});

You could also set this option on individual Ajax request.

Comment: Would this change how the request is displayed in the Developer Tools?

Comment: It should as JQuery will no longer append the timestamp to the url. When you say cache true it would stop appending timestamps.